# EPIPE on net.connect to an HTTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to connect to a node http server socket (expressJs) with net.connect in roder to pass that socket to my repl to be able to basically connect to my http server and launch commands.

when trying this I got the error EPIPE the second I started the repl.

here is the code for the repl:

```
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (args.length < 1) {
  process.exit(1);
}

const url = args[0];
const [host, port] = url.split(':');

//this will get the url to connect to
const socket = net.connect(parseInt(port), host);

process.stdin.pipe(socket);
socket.pipe(process.stdout);

Console.start({
  expose: { container, Metric:metricsObject},
  socket:socket
});
```

The start function :

```
start(options = {}) {
    const { expose, socket } = options;
    const repl = REPL.start({
        eval: promisableEval,
        terminal:true,
        input: socket,
        output: socket,
    });

    Object.assign(repl.context, expose);
}
```

The http server running :

```
const http = this.express
    .listen(this.config.web.port, () => {
      const { port } = http.address();
      this.logger.info(`[p ${process.pid}] Listening at port ${port}`);
      resolve();
    });
```

`this.express` is just an instance of express : `this.express = express();`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to connect to an http (or https?) server at a URL like `http://mine.example.com:3000/path/item` by saying

```
net.connect(parseInt('3000/path/item'), 'http://mine.example.com');
```

It won't work for a number of reasons.

1. Unless you're a pretty good programmer expert at the http protocol, you should not use `net.connect` to talk to http servers. Try using [http.clientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) instead.
2. hostnames passed to net.connect should be raw machine names like `'mine.example.com'` and not preceded by a protocol specifier.
3. ports, similar.

Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to do with stdin and stdout. But your `socket` would not be ready for use until its connect operation completes and you get an event announcing that.

You can use the old `telnet` program to connect to  an http server. It lets you type stuff to the server, and then displays what you get back.  In your case you'd do

```
 telnet localhost 3000  # from shell your command line
```

The server then connects and sits there waiting. You type

```
 GET / HTTPS/1.0
```

and then *two* `<Enter>`s. The server then sends back whatever it would send if you put `http://localhost:3000` into a browser location line. *It then closes the connection.*

I'm not sure how that http protocol operation fits into your REPL.

The example you mention at https://medium.com/trabe/mastering-the-node-js-repl-part-3-c0374be0d1bf doesn't connect to an http server, it connects to a tcp server. Http servers (including all node/express servers) are a subspecies of tcp server, but they layer the http protocol on the tcp protocol. The http protocol isn't suitable for the back-and-forth conversational style of REPLs.

Comment: the host and port I am using in the net.connect are exactly : 'localhost' and '3000' which are the exact host and port my web server is running on. with the stdin and stdout I am trying to link stdin of the repl process which I am running to my webserver on and the stdout of the server to my repl process. I am just trying to connect a repl to a running node http server

Comment: I did follow this a bit : https://medium.com/trabe/mastering-the-node-js-repl-part-3-c0374be0d1bf

Comment: so the socket I get from the http req.socket is not suitable for the tcp repl I am trying to use. how do I get the tcp socket out of the http socket since the latter is just a layer on top of the first.

Comment: My `telnet` example shows how to pretend an http connection is a plain tcp connection. But trying to hook a REPL to the tcp socket in an http connection is like trying to have a conversation with a soft-drink dispenser. All it knows how to do is deliver cans of Pepsi in response to requests. It's *really good* at doing that at large scale, but worthless for anything else.  Your intended project contains a category error.